# Unity Singleton

Tags: c#, unity3d, singleton

> Есть MainCamera на которой висят скрипты. Соответственно, мне нужно чтобы объект не удалялся при загрузке нового уровня (сцены). Оставляю объект строкой: DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject). Нужно при входе в главное меню удалить прежнюю MainCamera. Как мне это реализовать?

Вчера в ответ на мой вопрос получил вот такой код от пользователя trollingchar :

```
public sealed class UnitySingleton : MonoBehaviour {
    public static UnitySingleton Instance { get; private set; }

    private void Awake () {
        if (Instance) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
        else {
            DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
            Instance = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том что скрипт на Canvas(text) работает , а на объектах с box collider2d нет.
P.S. С синглтонами я работаю впервые , да и проблему ,наверное, недостаточно хорошо описал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте статический метод для удаления и обнуления ссылки на `Instance`:

```
public sealed class UnitySingleton : MonoBehaviour {
    public static UnitySingleton Instance { get; private set; }

    private void Awake() {
        if (Instance) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            Instance = this;
        }
    }

    public static void DeleteSingletonInstance() {
        if(Instance) {
            Destroy(Instance.gameObject);
            Instance = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Применение:

```
UnitySingleton.DeleteSingletonInstance();
```

---

Вообще, `Singleton` - это объект, который существует, пока программа не завершит свое выполнение. Если вам вдруг понадобилось какие-то скрипты хранить в виде одиночки - лучше сделать отдельный от камеры объект-одиночку с необходимыми скриптами и не привязывать к этому делу камеру.

Comment: Дело в том что DontDestroyOnLoad не работает и объекты удаляются .

Comment: @Veudd что значит "не работает"? Где не работает?

Comment: При переходе на другую сцену объекты удаляются .

Comment: Извините, моя ошибка.Я решил что могу использовать один и тот же скрипт для пару объектов.

Answer (score 0):

Есть также решение, когда мы имеем сцену, назовем ее **InitScene**, где храним объекты, не предназначенные для повторного создания. Вызываем у их родителя `DontDestroyOnLoad`, инициализируем там что нам нужно и загружаем сцену с главным меню **MainScene**. После этого **InitScene** больше не загружаем.